# UPSERT with SELECT in HANA

Tags: sql, hana, upsert

I am new to SQL and I want to do an UPSERT into a table with select from another table. For example I have 2 tables

```
TABLE1
ID   DATE         VALUE
1    23.09.2020   abc
2    01.02.2020   def

TABLE2
ID      VALUE  ADDRESS
1       xyz    mmm
2       zzz    nnn
2       zzz    ppp
3       ccc    qqq
```

The task is - If the ID in TABLE1 is of DATE = '23.09.2020' and ID is present in TABLE2 then update VALUE column in TABLE1 with the VALUE in TABLE2. And if ID in TABLE1 is present in TABLE2 but does not have DATE as '23.09.2020' then insert distinct (ID,VALUE) from TABLE2 into TABLE1. And if ID in TABLE1 is not present in TABLE2 then do nothing. So final result in TABLE1 after UPSERT should look like.

```
TABLE1
ID   DATE         VALUE
1    23.09.2020   xyz
2    01.02.2020   def
2    23.09.2020   zzz
```

NOTE : ID column is not a primary key, and I cannot make it as primary key.
I have tried something like below, but getting error and not able to achieve desired result.

```
upsert TABLE1(ID,DATE,VALUE)
SELECT DISTINCT ID,'23.09.2020',VALUE FROM TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID AND TABLE1.DATE = '23.09.2020'
```

**UPDATE** - I tried using MERGE as suggested, but getting ID = 2 inserted twice in TABLE1, where as I want it inserted only once as distinct (ID,VALUE) from TABLE2. Below is the MERGE query I tried.

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 T1 
USING TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.DATE = '23.09.2020' 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET T1.VALUE = T2.VALUE 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT(ID,DATE,VALUE) VALUES(T2.ID,'23.09.2020',T2.VALUE);
```

Result I am getting

```
TABLE1
ID   DATE         VALUE
1    23.09.2020   xyz
2    01.02.2020   def
2    23.09.2020   zzz
2    23.09.2020   zzz   --> Duplicate, not wanted.
```

Result I want

```
ID   DATE         VALUE
1    23.09.2020   xyz
2    01.02.2020   def
2    23.09.2020   zzz
```

How can I insert distinct of (ID,VALUE) from TABLE2 using MERGE query ?

Comment: I am not into hana , but why don't you go for `merge` as `upsert` preferred only when primary key is available ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Thanks for suggestion. I tried using merge but getting duplicate inserted. How can I get only distinct ID,VALUE inserted ? I have updated in question what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try with below,

You have almost done everything right as I see, what I did use a sub query to select the distinct `ID` and `VALUE` and then join.

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 T1 
USING (SELECT DISTINCT ID,VALUE 
         FROM TABLE2 T2
      ) T2
ON (    T1.ID = T2.ID
    AND T1.DATE = '23.09.2020')
WHEN MATCHED
 THEN 
    UPDATE SET T1.VALUE = T2.VALUE 
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN 
    INSERT(ID,DATE,VALUE) 
      VALUES(T2.ID,'23.09.2020',T2.VALUE);
```

Comment: Merge is applicable in case of primary key in merged data since if you have two values for the same non-key column, then DISTINCT does not solve the problem. You have to implement some sophisticated way to remove duplicates. Maybe the data he wants to insert is conforming this rule but in general it is not true. So I don't understand how someone wants to merge something without primary key in reference dataset.